# How to use a link in Main Menu to switch language of current page?

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

Now I have three links to switch language on Main Menu:

```
http://www.example.com/en
http://www.example.com/de
http://www.example.com/it
```

The problem is the above all links to the `<front>` page. How can make the links dynamic? Hopefully there is a:

```
http://www.example.com/it/<current_node> or
http://www.example.com/it/<current_page>
```

I tried [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) and [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) (to embed the [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown)) but failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you found solution of the issue?